# How to deploy to a stage a single endpoint on AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm finding pretty frustrating working with AWS API Gateway when collaborating with other colleagues, in particular I can't find a way to deploy a single endpoint without deploying the entire API snapshot which can include works by other colleagues.

I have the following scenario. I've created my wonderful API which contains 2 endpoints and I've deployed them on the `development` stage first and then on the `production` stage. Everything seemed to work perfectly so my colleague started his task creating a new endpoint and publishing it on the `development` stage. But then it happened that 1 of the 2 endpoints published previously had one bug: the lambda it used under the hood pointed at the `$LATEST` version and not to the correct version.
Now I have the following problem: I can fix that endpoint, but how can I deploy it without also deploying my colleague's endpoint? As far as I understood on AWS API Gateway deploying to a stage means taking a snapshot of the entire endpoints and publishing all together.

Comment: If you are doing Lambda functions with serverless package, you can use this: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/cli-reference/deploy-function